# How to write the name of a Github imported folder on my python code (discord.py)?

Tags: python, github, discord.py

I have a problem with my python bot code, I need to chdir to the folder where all my files are in Github but I don't know how to.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

`os.chdir("Game-Master /")`

And it gives me this error on logs:

```
2020-11-17T20:29:12.491976+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-17T20:29:15.869590+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python main.py`
2020-11-17T20:29:16.520541+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-17T20:29:18.493338+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-17T20:29:18.493358+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
2020-11-17T20:29:18.493535+00:00 app[worker.1]:     os.chdir("Game-Master /")
2020-11-17T20:29:18.493589+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Game-Master /'
```

Here's the important part of the code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import json
import random

os.chdir("Game-Master /")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", description = "organise des combats") 
token = str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN'))
bot.remove_command('help')
```

Comment: There is a space in your path. Is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: Maybe it's that Anpel I'll try without space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory was just . so i just needed to write '.' on chdir

`os.chdir('.')`

That was all

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Heroku is not able to change directories, mainly because it is working with a different directory. I had this same issue, and they told me that Heroku is not a suitable service for bot deployment. Maybe you can run it full-time?

Comment: That's not the problem here I just only need to call the name of the folder in Github it has no link with Heroku it only servs to see logs and to deploy the bot but hasn't any problem with Heroku.

Comment: Why do you need to change directories to this folder? You cannot change directories to something that isn't even stored locally.

Comment: I don't need to change the directory i just want to write the directory in os.chdir but i don't know how to write it correctly cause it is used in my Github

Comment: Because you are running it in heroku, the directory it is working with isn't in the same directory you are trying to change. To solve this, just run the bot full time instead of deploying it on heroku

Comment: But i need to run it on heroku cause i don't have money and it's a big project I also don't have the connection to run the bot full time so Heroku is the best for now.